# Retrieve related entities of each, using RetrieveMultipleRequest

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I'm trying to retrieve a list of entities from CRM, but I'd like to get each one with the related entities. So far, I've the following code:

```cs
FilterExpression filterExpression = new FilterExpression();
ConditionExpression condition = new ConditionExpression(Constants.ModifiedOnAttribute, ConditionOperator.GreaterEqual, lastSync);
filterExpression.AddCondition(condition);

QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression()
{
     EntityName = entityName,
     ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(attributesMetadata.Select(att => att.Name).ToArray<string>()),
     Criteria = filterExpression,
     Distinct = false,
     NoLock = true
};

RetrieveMultipleRequest multipleRequest = new RetrieveMultipleRequest();
multipleRequest.Query = queryExpression;

RetrieveMultipleResponse response = (RetrieveMultipleResponse)proxy.Execute(multipleRequest);
```

In the variable response, I can see the EntityCollection attribute, but inside, Related entities always come empty.

[image: Related entities count is 0]

I'd like to know if it is possible to retrieve the set of a given entities, with the related entities, using RetrieveMultipleRequest, rather than go one by one using RetrieveRequest.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One approach to retreive related entities data - adding LinkEntities to your query. Example below will make you an idea how to make this:

```cs
LinkEntity linkEntity = new LinkEntity("email", "new_emails", "activityid", "new_relatedemail", JoinOperator.Inner);
linkEntity.Columns.AddColumn("versionnumber");
linkEntity.Columns.AddColumn("new_emailsid");
linkEntity.EntityAlias = "related";

query = new QueryExpression("email");
query.ColumnSet.AddColumn("activityid");
query.ColumnSet.AddColumn("versionnumber");
query.Criteria.AddCondition("modifiedon", ConditionOperator.NotNull);
query.LinkEntities.Add(linkEntity);
```

And then you can access attributes from related entities using EntityAlias you specified above:

```cs
foreach (Entity entity in entities.Entities)
{
    if ((long)(entity["related.versionnumber"] as AliasedValue).Value > 0)
    {
        stop = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks SergeyS. That's not the best that I hope, but is what CRM offers :). If I have a list of 100 accounts with 5 related entities, with 3 records each one, I'll get 24.300 records from the server :S

Answer (score 5):

The `RetrieveMultipleRequest` is for returning multiple instances of a particular type of entity.  I have spent a year using the CRM SDK from C# and I have found no way of populating those related entity collections in a single query.  This basically leaves you with two options:

1. Use the AliasedValue as SergeyS recommends.  Remember when querying 1:Many relationships, be aware that you could be returning multiple results for the same parent entity.  This is what I use most of the time.
2. Perform a second query for each relationship you want access to.  You'll probably get better performance if you can use an `IN` statement in your second query, based on the results of the first, rather than performing a separate query for each result of the first.

Below is some pseudo code to show the difference.

```cs
var contacts = GetContacts();

// One Request to get the cars for the contacts
var cars = GetCarsWhereContactIdIn(contacts.Select( c => c.new_ContactId));

foreach(var c in contacts){
    c.new_Cars.AddRange(cars.where(car => car.new_contactId = c.ContactId));
}

// Verses
var contacts = GetContacts();

foreach(var c in contacts){
    // One Request for each contact
    c.new_Cars.AddRange(GetCarsForContact(c.ContactId));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Daryl. I think that some times, the second is the best approach. Anyway, I hope CRM guys give it as related entities in the future :)